# Perl - how to compare values of array with hash table

Tags: perl

New Perl User.

I'm trying to create a hash table from some tab delimited data stored in a variable `$blast_results` with the first column as the key.  And then I want to compare the the values in an array `@filenames` with the key in the hash table.  If the array value is found in the hash key, I want to print out a re-ordered structure of the `$blast_results`, if the array value is not in the hash, I want to print out the value followed by 'No Result Found'.

This is what I have thus far, I think the hash table is not correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data:Dumper;

#create variable to mimic blast results
my $blast_results = "file1.ab1  9   350 0.0 449 418 418 403479  403042  567
file3.ab1   2   833 0.0 895 877 877 3717226 3718105 984";

#create array to mimic filename array
my @filenames = ("file1.ab1", "file2.ab1", "file3.ab1");

#header for file
my $header = "Query\tSeq_length\tTarget found\tScore (Bits)\tExpect(E-value)\tAlign-length\tIdentities\tPositives\tChr\tStart\tEnd\n";

#initialize hash
my %hash;
#split blast results into array
my @row = split(/\s+/, $blast_results);
$hash{$row[0]}=$_;
print $header;
foreach my $file (@filenames){
    ## If this filename has an associated entry in the hash, print it in a re-ordered format
    if(defined($hash{$file})){
        print "$row[0]\t$row[9]\t$row[1]:$row[7]-$row[8]\t$row[2]\t$row[3]\t$row[4]\t$row[5]\t$row[6]\t$row[1]\t$row[7]\t$row[8]\n";
        }
    ## If not, print this.
    else{
        print "$file\t0\tNo Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed\n";
        }
    }
print "-----------------------------------\n";      
print "$blast_results\n"; #test what results look like
print "-----------------------------------\n"; 
print "$row[0]\t$row[1]\n"; #test if array is getting split correctly
print "-----------------------------------\n"; 
print "$filenames[2]\n"; #test if other array present
print "-----------------------------------\n";
print Dumper(\%hash);  #print out hash table
```

The result from this script is (the `@filenames` array is not matching the hash and the hash does not contain all of the data):

```
Query   Seq_length  Target found    Score (Bits)    Expect(E-value) Align-length    Identities  Positives   Chr Start   End
file1.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
file2.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
file3.ab1   0   No Blast Results: Sequencing Rxn Failed
-----------------------------------
file1.ab1   9   350 0.0 449 418 418 403479  403042  567
file3.ab1   2   833 0.0 895 877 877 3717226 3718105 984
-----------------------------------
file1.ab1   9
-----------------------------------
file3.ab1
-----------------------------------
$VAR1 = {
      'file1.ab1' => undef
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something very odd just here:

```
my %hash;
#split blast results into array
my @row = split(/\s+/, $blast_results);
$hash{$row[0]}=$_;
```

Your hash will have a single key - of 'file1.ab1' and... I can't see what `$_` will be at this point, but it's almost certainly what you want. (From your dumper output at the end, it's `undef`.)

At no point to you put anything else into this hash, which is why you get the result you do.

Is by any chance `blast_results` normally read from a file?

If so, something like this might work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @line     = split;
    my $filename = shift(@line);
    $hash{$filename} = join( " ", @line );
}

print Dumper \%hash;


__DATA__
file1.ab1  9   350 0.0 449 418 418 403479  403042  567
file3.ab1   2   833 0.0 895 877 877 3717226 3718105 984
```

If you're getting results from a command instead - why not try:

```
open ( my $blast_results, "|-", "blastn -query test.fa -outfmt 6" );
while ( <$blast_results> ) { 
    #parse line into hash
}
```

Comment: yes I was trying to modify something where the hash was loaded from file.  But I thought it might be better to just write to file at the end.  The real script runs a command line function like this `my $blast_result = blastn -query test.fa -outfmt 6;`  So I thought could just use that output in the variable to create a hash and then process the text file the way I wanted.

Comment: OK. Might be a job for `open` then, so you can go line by line. See edit.

Comment: So I was running the command line program with backticks, but using open instead will allow me to read line by line into the hash table?

Comment: Yes. Open like this opens a filehandle, just like `STDIN` - which you can read one line at a time.